# How can I make Chrome use the right autocomplete information?

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, credit-card, autofill

Is there any way to dictate to browsers which fields should use what autocomplete information?

I'm a developer working on an ecommerce web site. I ask as, right now, we have a checkout where users enter their basic info (Name, Email, Phone), followed by a zip/postcode field for an address lookup, followed by a full set of address fields (Company, Address, Address line 2, City, Region, Country, and zip/postcode field).

Now, I know by browser has all of the information in it for country, city, and so on. When I invoke autocomplete, however, the following happens:

1. Name, Email, and Phone are filled-in
2. The autocomplete postcode field is filled-in with the postcode
3. The address line is filled in
4. None of the other fields are filled-in

Secondly, I know I have credit card information stored in my browser, but the autocomplete does not pull this through.

Any help would be appreciated. I've searched on Google, but obviously my google-fu is weak as most of the results I find are just user-centric - how to add your address and enable the feature in chrome - not how to engineer a site so that chrome knows where to put the information..

Answer (score 0):

It can be controlled with 'x-autocompletetype' attribute. Take a look at this:
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.fr/2012/01/making-form-filling-faster-easier-and.html
http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Autocompletetype

Comment: doesn't work for me, did you try it successfully ? do you have a working example ?